# Custom spinners input type number without js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need create input type="number" with custom spinners. It need to be like that

[image]
How can I do that without js? or js needed here?

Comment: You can somewhat style the native buttons, but I don't think they can be styled like that.  
You can however remove them and create new buttons, but that would require javascript for the functionality and a couple of new elements.

Comment: I started, but takes too long, finish the styles yourself -> http://jsfiddle.net/eE7cs/

Comment: without js can not do? With js I have already done that, just wondering if it was possible without js.

Comment: I really want to understand why these people answer JS answers when the OP asked "without js". It means *without JS* guys, please do not answer JS solutions if you can do it with CSS.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the javascript/jQuery. You can use jQuery user interface plug in for spinner. **[Demo](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#default).**

In case of plugin you need to customize it as required, the arrows can be replaced and relocated by CSS stylings.

Or you can simply try this:

**Html:**

```
<a id="down" href="#" onclick="updateSpinner(this);">-</a><input id="content" value="0" type="text" style="width:30px" /><a id="up" href="#"  onclick="updateSpinner(this);">+</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function updateSpinner(obj)
{
    var contentObj = document.getElementById("content");
    var value = parseInt(contentObj.value);
    if(obj.id == "down") {
        value--;
    } else {
        value++;
    }
    contentObj.value = value;
}
```

I working example can be seen on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/hbP3y/).

Answer (score 4):

You can target the buttons in css using:

```
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{}
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{}
```

However, trying to achieve the design you wish to achieve might be hard and js might be you best option. The above css, also only works in webkit browsers as well (chrome, safari).

JS would be your safest and most cross browser friendly bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better version of the code by @AmanVirdi if you want no negative numbers and number not greater than 100.

For more than 100 just tweak the condition if(value > 99) for as much as you want.

```
function updateSpinner(obj)
{
    var contentObj = document.getElementById("content");
    var value = parseInt(contentObj.value);

    if(isNaN(value)){
            contentObj.value=0;
            return;
        }
    else{
    if(obj.id == "down" && value >= 1) {
        value--;
    } else if(obj.id == "up"){
        if(value > 99){alert("Max Value Reached"); contentObj.value=100; return;}
        value++;
    }
   }
    contentObj.value = value;
}
```